# How to add balloon pointer to window in WPF?

Tags: wpf, window, balloon-tip

I have been look for a way to create WPF Windows similar to MS Lync below, with a pointing arrow, but nothing except old tooltip approach. Can this be done?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement Balloon message in a WPF application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310102/how-to-implement-balloon-message-in-a-wpf-application)

Comment: Not a duplicate, I need window to have the arrow, not tooltip, not user control.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [How to Style WPF Tooltip Like a Speech Bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446250/how-to-style-wpf-tooltip-like-a-speech-bubble)

Seems like it should do exactly what you want.