# ToolTip is not showing in WPF Label?

Tags: c#, wpf

In application, I am trying to set a Tool-tip on Label control.
Please find the detail XAML, suggest to fix the issue if possible.
So far i have tried many tricks (e.g IsEnabled, IsHitTestVisible, control template, background setting...), but failed to display tooltip.

```
<UserControl x:Class="HSDLAdminPortal.Forms.Application.ApplicationDetailForm"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit"             
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HSDLAdminPortal.Forms.Application"
         mc:Ignorable="d" Width="1290" Height="595"
         xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"              
         xmlns:name="UserControl"
         >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="LabelInfoStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="LabelInfoValueStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#999966"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="LabelInfoHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Margin="4" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#e6eeff" Offset="1" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FFF5F2EF" Offset="0" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/CustomAccordion.xaml"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,-10,730,0" Background="Transparent" Panel.ZIndex="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <GroupBox Header=""  Margin="0,4,10,4" Height="540" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="532">
                <Canvas Margin="0,0,0,1">
                    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Stroke="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="493" Canvas.Left="17" Canvas.Top="201">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush  EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="1" />
                                <GradientStop Color="LightGray" />
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.5" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="295" Stroke="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="493" Canvas.Left="17" Canvas.Top="219"/>
                    <Image Stretch="Fill"  x:Name="ImagePhoto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="123"  Width="120" Source="/HSDLAdminPortal;component/Resources/photo_test.png" Canvas.Top="3" Canvas.Left="37"/>
                    <Label x:Name="LblPhoto" Content="Photo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Transparent"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold" Height="22" Width="62" Canvas.Top="124" Canvas.Left="75"/>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Height="128" Canvas.Left="37" Canvas.Top="1" Width="119"/>
                    <Rectangle Height="22" Canvas.Left="221"  Canvas.Top="1" Width="289">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush  EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="1" />
                                <GradientStop Color="LightGray" />
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.5" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="163" Stroke="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="289" Canvas.Left="221" Canvas.Top="23"/>
                    <Label x:Name="LblMiscellaneous" Style="{DynamicResource LabelInfoHeaderStyle}" Foreground="Black" Content="Miscellaneous" Background="Transparent" Canvas.Left="342" Canvas.Top="-1" Height="28" FontWeight="ExtraBold"/>
                    <Label x:Name="LblPersonalInfo" Style="{DynamicResource LabelInfoHeaderStyle}" Content="Personal Info" Foreground="Black" Background="Transparent" Canvas.Left="221" Canvas.Top="195" Height="54" Width="125" FontWeight="ExtraBold"/>

                    <Label x:Name="LblApplicantType" ToolTip="text tooltip" Style="{DynamicResource LabelInfoStyle}" Content="Applicant Type : " Background="Transparent" Canvas.Left="231" Canvas.Top="40" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <Label x:Name="LblApplicantTypeValue" Style="{DynamicResource LabelInfoValueStyle}" Content="N/A" Background="Transparent" Canvas.Left="360" Canvas.Top="40"  FontWeight="Bold"/>

                    <Label x:Name="LblApplicantNameValue" Style="{DynamicResource LabelInfoValueStyle}" ToolTip="Sample ToolTip" Content="N/A" ToolTip="Sample ToolTip" Background="Transparent" Canvas.Left="190" Canvas.Top="220"  FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <Image x:Name="ImageSignature" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="37"  Width="97" Source="/HSDLAdminPortal;component/Resources/signature.png" Canvas.Top="149" Canvas.Left="52"/>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Height="44" Canvas.Left="37" Canvas.Top="142" Width="119"/>
                    <Label x:Name="LblSignature" Content="Signature" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Transparent"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold" Height="36" Width="62" Canvas.Top="181" Canvas.Left="69"/>
                    <Canvas x:Name="AttachmentDetailsCanvas" Width="520" Height="501"  Visibility="Visible" Opacity="0">
                        <Canvas.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush  EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="1" />
                                <GradientStop Color="LightGray" />
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.5" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>

                        </Canvas.Background>

                        <Rectangle Height="45" Canvas.Left="0"  Canvas.Top="1" Width="520">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush  EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="1.2" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="LightGray" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#0077b3" Offset="0" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Label x:Name="attachmentDetails" Content="Attachment Details" Foreground="White"  Background="Transparent" FontSize="20"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  FontWeight="Bold" Height="36" Width="220" Canvas.Top="4" Canvas.Left="143" />

                        <Image Source="/Resources/Images/attachment.png" Height="400" Width="510" Canvas.Top="86" x:Name="atcImg"/>
                        <Button ToolTip="Click To Hide Image" x:Name="hideImageButtonButton" Width="42" Height="42" Click="hideImageButton_Click" Canvas.Left="478" Canvas.Top="1">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image x:Name="close_image" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="/Resources/hide.png" Height="42" Width="42" OpacityMask="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                    </Canvas>
                </Canvas>
            </GroupBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: If I remove the Style, the tooltip is working fine. Check if your style is doing something with your tooltip.

Comment: Your local Style declaration takes precedence over your tool tip property, to be able to help you with what you want, show us the resource

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx Dependency Property Value Precedence

Comment: @JosepB. I have removed the style, still it's not working. :(

Comment: Check if the control or the label is disabled. Tooltip by default only works for enabled controls.

Comment: @GhostDeveloper, still not working? was it enabled?

Comment: yes, it's enabled but not working. look at the updated image.

Comment: Hmm that is quite weird, could you try adding it like so, <Label.ToolTip> Hello </Label.ToolTip> </Label>

Comment: also why not just paste the code, so we can try it? :p

Comment: @Ghost, so did my solution work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of following image (attachment.png) was placed at the same position of labels, but not showing because of 0 opacity (at parent control). Now i use Visibility of image instead of Opacity & it fix my issue. thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

> Explicit style. The Style property is set directly. In most scenarios,
>   the style is not defined inline, but instead is referenced as a
>   resource, by explicit key. In this case the Style property itself acts
>   as if it were a local value, precedence item 3.

MSDN website on precedence.

As the Style is set as a local value it takes precedence over the next local value.

Add Tooltip to your style and add the text you want there for it to work with your dynamic resource

**UPDATE**

After looking at your code, it is clear that your label is just covered by a transparent grid, so your mouseover never really goes over it.
Put, Panel.ZIndex="1" and it will work as this brings your label in front of everything

I would also look at the MSDN website, if you plan on using more than one zindex to overcome your problem, just to learn more about it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex(v=vs.110).aspx

```
  <Label x:Name="LblApplicantNameValue" Panel.ZIndex="1" Style="{DynamicResource LabelInfoValueStyle}" ToolTip="Sample ToolTip" Content="this label now works"  Background="Transparent" Canvas.Left="360" Canvas.Top="66"  FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

Comment: for label applicant name you have tooltip set twice

Comment: @GhostDeveloper. solved your issue in my answer above, please mark it as correct when it works:) (the green tick)

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but unfortunately it's not working.
In the mean time i found the solution.
"attachment.png" was placed on the same position of labels, that's why it's not working. thanks :)

Comment: mkay, well I had to remove the png, to run the code as I didn't have the resources, but good find, was a similar issue, something covering the label

Answer (score 0):

You can style the tool tip by overriding the template of ToolTip control as did in the question [How to style WPF tooltip like a speech bubble?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446250/how-to-style-wpf-tooltip-like-a-speech-bubble)